# Update post using json api v2

Tags: plugin-json-api

I'm trying to update a post using the json api Version 2.0-beta13.1. It returns success but doesn't modify the post. I'm doing it from Python but I don't think there should be anything special about that.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

data = {
    'title': 'my new title'
    }
resp = requests.put('http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/8', data=json.dumps(data), auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userid, passwd))
print(resp.text)
```

I've tried post, put, various fields.. But it just reports success and ignores me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using requests wrong. This seems to fix it:

```
resp = requests.request('put', 'http://localhost:8000/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/8', json=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(userid, passwd))
```